# Mysql command could not implement stored procedure

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am new to Mysql. I want to create a stored procedure that update the price for a product. I use jdbc to implement this stored procedure.But my stored procedure command failed many times. The following is mysql code. "p" means product, "des" means the decrease in price and "pro" means product name. The CallableStatement in java will give the product name and the decrease for that the product's price. Thus the stored procedure will decrease the price for the corresponding product.

```
`CREATE PROCEDURE updateP(IN pro CHAR(10), IN des INT)`
`
BEGIN`
     UPDATE customers
    `DECLARE p INT;`
    `SET p = (SELECT price FROM customers WHERE product= pro);`
    `SELECT p;`
    `p = p - des;`
END
```

Comment: Your stored procedure doesn't make sense. 1. You are selecting price from a table called customers (is this correct?) 2. `p = p - des` are all operations performed on `CHAR` you need to make them some type of numeric value if you want to subtract them. 3. I would assume that you want to update a table at some point and I don't see any `update` statements anywhere. Please clarify a bit better your goal.

Comment: Thx for replying. Customers is the table, and price is the attribute of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is all you need:

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE PROCEDURE updateP(IN pro CHAR(10), IN des INT)

BEGIN
    UPDATE customers
    SET price = price-des 
    WHERE product= pro;

END$

DELIMITER ;
```

That should decrease the current price by the decrease amount passed in as parameter.

One suggestion: don't name your procedures `updateP` use full names like `sprocUpdateProduct` or `UpdateProduct_sp`; if tomorrow you need to update a person you no longer will know whether `updateP` updates a `Person` or a `Product`. The same goes for variables, use full names.

Comment: @user1015798 I added a semicolon after the `Where` clause. To be honest, It's been more than 6 years since I don't write a stored proc on MySQL but as far as I remember, you only need the semicolon where I placed it. Maybe someone else here can confirm?

Comment: @Icarus You do need a semi-colon. Just remember to set the delimiter to something other than a semi-colon before and after the procedure code as part of your script. I'll try and edit your post.